# Can friendly-id gem work with capital letters in url e.g. /users/joe-blogs and /users/Joe-Blogs both work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I like the friendly id gem but one problem i'm seeing is when I type in a url with a capitol letter in it such as /users/Joe-Blogs it cant find the page. Its a little trivial but most sites can handle something like this and will generate the page whether it has a capitol letter or not. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Edit: to clarify this is for when users enter a url manually and put capitals in it just because its a name like author/Joe-Blogs. I've seen other sites handle this but rails seems to just give a 404.

Comment: URLs after the hostname are case-sensitive, so the ones with capital letters strictly shouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

`friendly_id` uses `parameterize` to create the slugs.

I think the best way to solve your problem is to parameterize the params before using it to find.

```
# controller
User.find(params[:id].parameterize)
```

Or parameterize the url where the link originated from.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to `Vic`'s answer, you'll want to look at [`url normalization`](http://wiredimpact.com/blog/never-use-capital-letters-urls/):

> The following normalizations are described in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) to result in equivalent URLs:

> **Converting the scheme and host to lower case.**
>
> The scheme and host components of the URL are case-insensitive. Most normalizers will convert them to lowercase.
>
> Example: HTTP://www.Example.com/ → http://www.example.com/

In short - it's against convention to use capitalization in your urls.

You may also wish to look at `URI normalize`; more importantly, you should work to remove the capitalization from your URLs:

```
URI.parse(params[:id]).normalize
```

Comment: My URLs don't have any capitalisation in them but i was being a little nit picky and thought I'd see id there was a fix for users who end up putting capitals in the URL. (Got a site with urls like author/joe-sam and some users manually put /author/Joe-Sam with capitals for whatever reason)

Comment: This is not what the author asked. You're talking about scheme and host, scheme is (in a nutshell) http/https and host is (in a nutshell) the domain. What RFC 3986 says about URL *path* is "6.2.2.1.  Case Normalization: The other generic syntax components are assumed to be case-sensitive unless specifically defined otherwise by the scheme (see Section 6.2.3)."